# Difference between \big[ and \bigl[

Tags: math-mode, brackets, delimiters

What is the difference between `\big[` (or equivalently `\big(`) and `\bigl[`? Is it always necessary to mention `l` (left) and `r` (right)?

Comment: It's also instructive to consider the open interval notation, `$]x[$` vs. `$\left]x\right[$` or any of the `\big` versions.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`\bigl` declares an opening math delimiter with less horizontal spacing than the unspecified `\big`. `\bigr` defines a closing math delimiter. Using a `\bigl` and `\bigr` pair you could get the brackets or parentheses closer to the term within.

Just compare:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\bigl[ \times \bigr]$

$\big[ \times \big]$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The definitions in latex.ltx are:

```
\def\bigl{\mathopen\big}
\def\bigm{\mathrel\big}
\def\bigr{\mathclose\big}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this distinction without specifying a larger size?

Comment: For normal brackets it's automatically done. Compare `$[ \times ]$` to `$\mathord[ \times \mathord]$`.

Comment: What you're saying is that `[` is automatically interpreted as an opening math delimiter, so one must manually force it not to be, if desired; is that right?

Comment: That's true. fontmath.ltx defines: `\DeclareMathDelimiter{[}{\mathopen} {operators}{"5B}{largesymbols}{"02}`

Comment: Does the same spacing issue happen to `[x]` and `\left[x\right]`?

Comment: @Mark Meckes :  This reply is kind of late, but yes.  You can see it in the definitions at the bottom of the answer: \mathopen on the left and \mathclose on the right.

Answer (score 26):

You can see the difference in the following example. The left modifiers `\bigl` etc. are basically `\mathopen{}\big`. You also have to use `\mathopen` if you are using `\left` and `\right` to do automatic scaling to get correct spacing in some cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  x &= \sin\biggl(\frac12\biggr)          \\ % good
  x &= \sin\mathopen{}\bigg(\frac12\bigg) \\ % good
  x &= \sin\bigg(\frac12\bigg)            \\ % bad
  x &= \sin\left(\frac12\right)           \\ % bad
  x &= \sin\mathopen{}\left(\frac12\right)   % good
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see. So what I now understand is that one should use `\mathopen{}` for a function, _e.g._, `f\mathopen{}\left(x^{2^2}\right)`, but don’t use it for a multiplication, _e.g._, `x \cdot \left(x^{2^2}\right) = x \left(x^{2^2}\right)`. It would be great if someone with some typographic experience could confirm! (Alternatively, I could open a new question.)

Comment: It's not 100% clean when one should use either. Is `\mathopen{}` only for function arguments?