# What is the correct way to do delimiters?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I've always used `\left` and `\right` with my delimiters, but [Martin Heller's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/difference-between-big-and-bigl/1234#1234) to [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/difference-between-big-and-bigl) indicates that this method gives incorrect spacing. The correction appears to be prepending `\mathopen{}`. Is this the canonical "correct" method? And what exactly does the `\mathopen` command do? A quick Google search does not turn up much useful information on it.

The other alternative offered involved the `\biggl` and `\biggr` commands and their ilk. I've never quite felt comfortable with using these because it doesn't feel right to specify these sizes manually. Is there a reason to prefer these commands to `\left` and `\right`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right/) addresses the spacing problems with `\left` and `\right` and the relationship with `\mathopen` and `\mathclose`.

Answer (score 11):

From the TeXBook:

> At this point you are probably wondering why should you bother learning about `\bigl` and `\bigr` and their relatives, when `\left` and `\right` are there [...] There are at least three situations in which you will want to use your wisdom [...]:
>
> 1. Sometimes `\left` and `\right` use a smaller delimiter than you want. For example, [...] `$\left|\left|x\right|-\left|y\right|\right|$`.
> 2. Sometimes `\left` and `\right` choose a larger delimiter than you want. For example, [...] `$$\left( \sum_{k=1}^n A_k \right)$$`.
> 3. Sometimes you need to break a huge formula into two or more separate lines, and you want to make sure that its opening and closing delimiters have the same size; but you can't use `\left` on the first line and `\right` on the last, since `\left` and `\right` must occur in pairs.
>
> [...] Of course, one of the advantages of `\left` and `\right` is that they can make arbitrarily large delimiters.

Answer (score 9):

Well, in most cases `\left` and `\right` are not needed. Often the size of delimiters does not need to be changed. For example `$(a+b)$` is enough and gives the same result as `$\left(a+b\right)$`. There are many cases where `\left` and `\right` choose the wrong sizes, for example `$\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty ... \right)$` gives most likely far to big delimiters, better is to select the appropriate size yourself. `$\Bigl( \sum ...\Bigr)$` is probably what I would do (I just finished typing my PhD thesis in maths and have not used a single time the `\left` or `\right` command).

`\mathopen` belongs with `\mathord`, `\mathop`, `\mathbin`, `\mathrel`, `\mathclose` and `\mathpunct` to a family of commands which changes the classes of individual characters or whole subformulas in mathmode. More information can be found in Knuth's "The TeXbook", p. 154ff.

Comment: I agree, typically \left and \right don't do the right thing; you'll need to fine-tune the typesetting manually by using something like \Bigl, \biggl, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Martin's answer is specifically about spacing following so called 'large operators'. Those  are operators like `\int` and `\sum`, but also the goniometric functions `\sin`, `\cos`, et cetera. The special thing about those is that these operators are followed by a delimited argument. In all other cases, `\left` and `\right` work just fine.

Comment: Hmm interesting. Can you explain a bit more what 'goniometric functions' are? Does this apply to `\Pr`?

Comment: In English, "goniometric" functions are more commonly known as trigonometric functions.  I don't think that this is a TeXnical term :)

Comment: I was going to post this as a separate question, but probably better here so there's no duplication: so the rule of thumb is that one should use \bigl,\bigr for operators and \left, \right for everything else, correct? What is used for enclosing arrays?

Comment: Use (the equivalent of, in a macro) `\sin\mathopen{}\left(` but otherwise `\left(` shouldn't have spacing problems.