# Difference between \langle and <

Tags: math-mode

Is there any difference between `\langle S \rangle` and  `\left< S \right>`? Or is `\langle` just an alias for `<` that by default works on one line without having to use `\left`?

Comment: Unrelated to TeX, but in Unicode: <> are U+003C/U+003E LESS-THAN SIGN/GREATER-THAN SIGN, while ⟨⟩ are U+27E8(/U+27E9) MATHEMATICAL LEFT(/RIGHT) ANGLE BRACKET. Also punctuation: ‹› U+2039(/U+203A) SINGLE LEFT/(RIGHT)-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK. Then as wide characters (CJK), there are 〈〉 U+3008/U+3009 LEFT/RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET; and (deprecated) 〈〉 (deprecated) U+2329/U+232A LEFT/RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE BRACKET (both deprecated). There are also ornaments like ❬❭ (U+276C and U+276D), ❮❯ (U+276E and U+276F), ❰❱ (U+2770 and U+2771). Hopefully when I next search for langle/rangle I can find this :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`<...>` just puts in the font's normal '<' and '>' characters as binary relations. As Mark S. Everitt said, you almost never want this.

`\langle ...\rangle` inserts a completely different set of characters which are narrower and taller than '<' and '>'. It also puts them in as *delimiters*, which means they get special spacing and have a slightly different shape in `\scriptstyle` (used for, e.g., superscripts).

`\left<...\right>` is an alias for `\left\langle ...\right\rangle`. These do *not* do the same thing as `\langle ...\rangle`! The differences are described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12793/9092), but the main things are that `\left<...\right>` scales to its contents and adds extra space sometimes.

EDIT: Another important difference is that `\langle` and `\rangle` (or `\bigl<` and `\bigr>`) may be used alone, since they're *just* delimiters. `\left` must *always* be followed by `\right`, which is why `\right.` (the blank delimiter) exists. Also, in case it wasn't clear, `\langle` does not really care what's in the rest of the equation, since it doesn't scale to contents.

Answer (score 28):

Don't use `<` or `>` like this. They are relations, whereas `\langle` and `\rangle` are delimiters. If you find typing them laborious, wrap them in macros (I do this with new commands like `\ket{...}` and `\bra{...}`.

Without `\left` and `\right` prepended to both, you get these:

[image]

With `\left` and `\right` on *both* the output is the same (both resize automatically) as you note in the question. I *strongly* advise you to use `\langle` and `\rangle` (with or without `\left` and `\right`) because every time I see a Dirac ket like this

[image]

my eyes bleed. If you always use `\langle` and `\rangle` then you can treat them just like other types of variable sized delimiter and get no ugly surprises. I know that this doesn't quite answer your question, but there may be people looking at this question who didn't realise you could use `>` like this and I want to nip that in the bud right now!

Comment: I kinda knew that; |A> makes me twitch as well. I just wanted to know if there was any difference in the TeX or if langle was an alias. But thanks for getting the message across. :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I saw `>` and had a bit of an allergic reaction! I am aware that the question was really one of what's going on behind the scenes though. :)

Comment: +1 for bleeding eyes with poor quantum mechanics notation

Comment: My brain bleeds whenever I see bra ket notation. I just never got my head around it.

Comment: @Seamus: It avoids a lot of integration, and that makes my brain bleed more. Lesser of two evils.