# How to make an equation more compact?

Tags: spacing, equations

I have an equation that wastes a lot of space around the union symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
RA_U  \left ( new , ref \right ) =
\bigcup_{
  \left\{ 
    i  \text{ such that }  f_i \left(  ref \right) < f_i \left( new \right) 
  \right\} 
}
\left\{ 
  X \in \mathbb{R}^M ; 
  x_i \in \left [ f_i \left(  ref \right) ; f_i \left( new \right) \right ] 
\right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is especially dreadful, since I am using `IEEEtran.cls`, which has two columns.

How can I compress the equation around the union symbol?

Comment: Don't use the `cmex10` option for `amsmath`; it's just for compatibility with ***very old*** TeX distributions.

Comment: I can't see the meaning of this formula. Is `$X=(x_1,x_2,...x_m)$`? If so, you are quantifying over `$i$` twice, once in the `\bigcup` and again in the set to its right. This is a mathematical error.

Comment: I second Dan's comment. Ignoring that, it usually is sufficiently clear to simply have `f_i(ref) < f_i(old)` below the `\bigcup` since i is the only free variable.

Comment: Gnnnn ... must .... not .... give .... stupid ... answer ... to ... title ...... gaaahdamnIcantresist: algebra!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `\mathclap` from `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
RA_U  ( \mathit{new}, \mathit{ref} ) =
\bigcup_{\mathclap{
  \left\{
    i  \text{ such that }  f_i (\mathit{ref}) < f_i ( \mathit{new} )
  \right\}
}}
\left\{
  X \in \mathbb{R}^M ;
  x_i \in [ f_i ( \mathit{ref} ) ; f_i ( \mathit{new} ) ]
\right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Better than mine, but I think that a qquad space on either side of the `\bigcup` will make it look much better (or pushing the subscript a bit down vertically with some `\strut`).

Comment: @Rmano This is left to the OP's taste.

Comment: Hmmm, something bad will happen if one put two `\bigcup_{\mathclap{\text{longgggg}}}`s together. Having no idea about this further more question, I got a ':(' from myself...

Comment: @Ch'enMeng, you can either let TeX arrange your equations, or take matters in your own hands. If you don't want to mash two subscripts together, just don't do it.

Answer (score 34):

I recommend you do the following:

- Get rid of all `\left` and `\right` directives since they (a) insert undesirable horizontal whitespace and (b) don't actually do anything useful in the present context.
- Use `\substack` (provided by the `amsmath` package) to break the line below `\bigcup` into two parts.
- Use `\textup` (or `\textnormal`) instead of the default math italics in the definitions of the variable names "ref" and "new".
- Use `\mathclap` (provided by the `mathtools` package) to suppress whitespace to the left and right of `\bigcup`. (This step is also featured in @karlkoeller's answer.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\newcommand\vnew{\textup{new}}
\newcommand\vref{\textup{ref}}
\begin{document}
Before: 
\begin{equation}
RA_U  \left ( new , ref \right ) =
\bigcup_{
  \left\{
    i  \text{ such that }  f_i \left(  ref \right) < f_i \left( new \right)
  \right\}
}
\left\{
  X \in \mathbb{R}^M ;
  x_i \in \left [ f_i \left(  ref \right) ; f_i \left( new \right) \right ]
\right\}
\end{equation}

After:
\begin{equation}
RA_U (\vnew,\vref) =
\bigcup_{ \mathclap{ \substack{i\text{ such that}\\f_i(\vref) < f_i(\vnew)}} } \,
\bigl\{ X\in\mathbb{R}^M ; x_i \in [ f_i(\vref) ; f_i(\vnew) ] \bigr\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would leave _some_ space around `\bigcup`. Other than that, this looks very good to me :)

Comment: @tohecz - Thanks! I did insert `\,` (thinspace) to the right of `\bigcup` ... :-) Since space is at a premium, I chose not to insert any more space.

Answer (score 16):

This is not new with respect to other answers, but I'd like to introduce a couple of tricks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\V}[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % or \mathit
\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\R}{\numberset{R}}

\begin{document}
This is the original equation
\begin{equation}
RA_{U}(\V{new},\V{ref}) =
\bigcup_{
  \quad
    \mathclap{\substack{
    \text{$i$ such that}\\[\jot]
    f_i(\V{ref}) < f_i(\V{new})
  }}
  \quad
}
\{ 
  X \in \R^{M} : 
  x_i \in [f_i(\V{ref}); f_i(\V{new})] 
\}
\end{equation}

\renewcommand{\V}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\renewcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}

Just to see the effect of changing just a couple of commands
\begin{equation}
RA_{U}(\V{new},\V{ref}) =
\bigcup_{
  \quad
    \mathclap{\substack{
    \text{$i$ such that}\\[\jot]
    f_i(\V{ref}) < f_i(\V{new})
  }}
  \quad
}
\{ 
  X \in \R^{M} : 
  x_i \in [f_i(\V{ref}); f_i(\V{new})] 
\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The main trick is the macro `\V` for typesetting multiletter variables; then also `\numberset` is defined, which is used indirectly for defining `\R` (and other number sets). I show how, just changing those definitions, one can change the output.

For the wide subscript I use `\substack` in a `\mathclap`, but adding some space around it in order that the union symbol is not adjacent to its surroundings.

Note the `\jot` used for giving some room between the two lines in the subscript. Also `\text{$i$ such that}` is handier to type than `i\text{ such that}`, because spaces are ‘natural’.

[image]

Comment: The `\V` macro is really nifty!

Comment: What is your view on the relative advantages of using `\textup` vs. `\mathrm` for typesetting variable names (assuming, of course, that an upright font shape is to be used)? In my experience, `\textup` yields slightly more tightly spaced letters, which may (or may not...) be desirable.

Comment: @Mico The difference is that one is typeset as normal text, the other in math, which has different rules for kerning. For variable names probably `\mathrm` (just like operator names); for words in subscript probably text; example: `$F_{\textup{eff}}$`. Maybe `\textnormal` is even better.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly don;t use `\left...\right` all over the place, it is not a good idea.

Why not just write `\{ i \mid  f_i (  ref ) < f_i ( new ) \}` ( it looks better to add space around the `|`)

Comment: What is objectionable about using `\left...\right`?

Comment: @Olivier I am also trying to find out. This seems to be a good resource http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/or-left-parentheses

Comment: Hmmm, bypassing the problem rather than sloving it...

Comment: @OlivierBégassat - Since space is at a premium in the present equation, all instructions that needlessly insert whitespace should be avoided, right?

Comment: Use `\left...\right` when appropriate. Trying to auto scale all over the places makes the code much harder to read. There is no reason to use scaling in say `\left( new \right)` as the fenced material is not tall. Instead it just clutters the code.

Comment: @Ch'enMeng You would be surprised how many good answers here actually do not answer the question _asked_, but rather solve the one the OP _wanted to ask_ ;)

Answer (score 5):

I would write the index to the joint in two lines as

[image]

You can obtain this through

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
RA_U  \left ( new , ref \right ) =
\mkern-36mu
\bigcup_{
  i, \atop f_i \left(  ref \right) < f_i \left( new \right) 
}
\mkern-36mu
\left\{ 
  X \in \mathbb{R}^M ; 
  x_i \in \left [ f_i \left(  ref \right) ; f_i \left( new \right) \right ] 
\right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Note that I addtionally customized the kerning by hand. You can use the `mathtools` package as well (see @Micos answers for example).

### Edit

According to @egregs comment I'd like to present a variety using the `\substack` command provided by `amsmath` that yelds better results regarding the size of the index:

```
\begin{equation}
RA_U  \left ( new , ref \right ) =
\mkern-40mu
\bigcup_{
  \substack{
    i, \\
    f_i \left(  ref \right) < f_i \left( new \right) 
  }
}
\mkern-40mu
\left\{ 
  X \in \mathbb{R}^M ; 
  x_i \in \left [ f_i \left(  ref \right) ; f_i \left( new \right) \right ] 
\right\}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: `amsmath` has `\substack` which is better than `\atop`.

Answer (score 2):

It is visual formatting, so it's better avoided if you can, but you can do:

```
\begin{equation}
RA_U  \left ( new , ref \right ) =
\qquad\bigcup_{\mathstrut\makebox[0pt][c]{$
  \left\{ 
    i  \text{ such that }  f_i \left(  ref \right) < f_i \left( new \right) 
  \right\} $}
}
\qquad \left\{ 
  X \in \mathbb{R}^M ; 
  x_i \in \left [ f_i \left(  ref \right) ; f_i \left( new \right) \right ] 
\right\}
\end{equation}
```

To obtain

[image]