# Underbrace without pushing equation

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, text

I'm using `\underbrace{}_\text{}` to explain the meaning of a variable:
[image: equation using underbrace]
As you can see in the image, underbrace pushes the equations aside to make space for the text. I would like to get something like this instead:
[image]

**Question:** Is it possible to remove this pushing behavior to get the desired result?

Thanks for helping! :D

Comment: [How to make an equation more compact?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146401/106162) seems relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way: you can use `\makebox[0pt]` and the relevant text size (`\footnotesize` or `scriptsize`), or `\clap`, defined in `mathtools`. Using some code in `mathtools`, we can define an `\EV` and a `\given` commands for the *expected value* of a random variable, which has variable-sized delimiters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
 \usepackage{mathtools}

\providecommand\given{}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\EV[1]{E}[]{}{
\renewcommand\given{\nonscript\:\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:}
#1}

\begin{document}

\[ \EV{R_{i, t}\given I_{t-1}} = γ_{0,t-1} + \underbrace{\gamma_{0,t-1}}_{\makebox[0pt]{\footnotesize conditional market risk premium}}β_{i, t-1} \]%
\bigskip
\[ \EV[\big]{R_{i, t}\given I_{t-1}} = γ_{0,t-1} + \underbrace{\gamma_{0,t-1}}_{\clap{\scriptsize conditional market risk premium}}β_{i, t-1} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly! For future reference: `\footnotesize` makes the text have the same size as footnotes, if you remove it you get a bigger text underneath the equation; `\makebox` creates a box to contain text.

Comment: I don't think a bigger size is advisable here. Actually, maths in underbrace is typed in scriptstyle, so text might even be typed in `\scriptsize`.

Comment: Here's a convenience function: `\newcommand{\myunderbrace}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_{\makebox[0pt]{\scriptsize \ensuremath{#2}}}}`. I believe an overbrace equivalent would be pretty much the same, just with the `\overbrace` and `^` replacements.