# User-defined parentheses that can span across more lines

Tags: brackets, robust-commands

I usually define some command of the kind

```
\newcommand{\paren}[#1]{\left(#1\right)}
```

to make the use of parentheses more agile.
Now, if in the body of my document I do this

```
\begin{align}
z = \paren{y\\+z}
\end{align}
```

I get a long list of complaints on the last line of the `align` environment, while I would expect the same output as for the following code,

```
\begin{align}
z = \left(y\\+z\right)
\end{align}
```

Anybody can let me know how to make this sort of parentheses commands robust over line breaks?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\paren}[1]{\left(#1\right)}



\begin{document}


% This works, but I don't like it.
\begin{align}
z = \left(y\right.\\
\left.+z\right)
\end{align}

% This is lovely, but does not work.
%\begin{align}
%z = \paren{y\\+z}
%\end{align}

% No complaints, of course, if the line break is removed
\begin{align}
z = \paren{y+z}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) in general using `\left...\right` every time is a bad idea. For one, it is unbreakable. Plus `\left(\\\right)` hides ``\\`` from `align`, so it will never work. I'd say that in general such an approach is not worth it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your first example does not work and I would be very surprised if it does for you. If you use some ` \\ ` in between your parentheses, you have to end the first line by `\right.` and start the next line with `\left.`

Comment: And the `\left A \right. \\ \left. B \right` approach may be faulty too, if `A` and `B` are not the same size. Manually scaling fences that are to be broken is almost always better.

Comment: @Antonio, try replacing `y` by `\frac{1}{2}` and you will see the problem with the approach

Comment: See the postings [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/5001) and [“(” or “\left(” parentheses?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12773/5001) for a more in-depth examinaton of why it's *not* good practice to use `\left(` and `\right)` everywhere.

Comment: Thanks everybody. The reasons you mentioned are exactly why I would like to find a command for parentheses that allows line breaks, and - why not - handles parentheses dimensions correctly across line breaks. What I was asking is if there is such a command in some package or if I can make a macro that does the trick.

Comment: It might be doable, but you will need some parsing, plus the macro will have to be made in such a manner that it does not hide `&` or ``\\`` from envs like `align`. It might be doable. But as mentioned, I do not think it is worth ot, it will also make the code much less readable.

Comment: Your question's formulation is misleading: you seem to say that ``\begin{align}
z = \left(y\\+z\right)
\end{align}`` is ok, which it is *not*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `mathtools` offers a command `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` to be put in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\paren}{\lparen}{\rparen}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\paren{a+\\
b = 3
}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

However, one needs to manually resize the delimiter.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\paren[\bigg]{a+\\
b = 3
}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments it is not recommended, and such a solution will make the code much less readable.

That being said, it can be done. This use a trick suggested by Sebastien Gouezel
cited from the `mathtools` manual

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
  \bgroup
  \catcode`\&=9
  \let\\\relax%
  \scantokens{#1}%
  \egroup
}

\newcommand\paren[1]{
  \left(\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#1}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.
  #1
  \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#1}}\right)
}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  A  = {} & \paren{ \frac12 \\ & +3 } 
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

I would still manually scale fences in such a situation, as in

```
\begin{align*}
  A = {} & \biggl( \frac12
  \\
  & +3 \biggr)
\end{align*}
```

which in my opinion is a lot more readable.