# Using left( and right) by default

Tags: parenthesis

It is very rare for me to need a parenthesis without `\left` and `\right`.
Is there a way to redefine the parenthesis `()` to being treated as if I wrote
`\left(` and `\right)`. 
Of course, I would need another command
`\noleft(` and `\noright)`
or something similar to get back the original meaning.

I know I can run a Perl script before every latex compilation to achieve this, but I am looking for a LaTeX solution.

Comment: *It is very rare for me to need a parenthesis without `\left` and `\right`*… How so? Can you give an example of an expression? (If it's a minimal compilable document, even better, just to save a few keystrokes to the people that's going to help you.)

Comment: Overusing `\left` and `\right` is a bad idea: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right?lq=1. Please think carefully about this. It's possible that when you say it's rare for you to need parentheses without `\left` and `\right` you are, in fact, not using them correctly. Only use them if you need to scale the delimeters - and there, you may still be better off manually selecting e.g. `\bigl(`

Comment: If you're looking for information as to why autosizing all parentheses -- e.g., via `\left(` and `\right)` -- is *not* advisable from a typographic point of view, please see the postings [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/5001) and ["(" or "\left(" parentheses?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12773/5001)