# The begin align and end align environment

Tags: align

I've just got a, what is, hopefully simple question about the use of the `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` environment delimiters. I have a single equation to write in between such commands.

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{split}
    A &= \left(B + \dots \\&+ \dots C \right)
  \end{split}
\end{align}
```

On one line I start the equation with a bracket which is fitted to the equation so make use of `\left` but the closure of this, defined by the corresponding `\right` bracket is on a different line and I am getting an error.

Is there an easy fix of this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\left( ... \right)` cannot span lines.

Either use `\right.` and `\left.` like so:

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{split}
    A &= \left(B + \dots\right. \\
      &+ \left.\dots C \right)
  \end{split}
\end{align}
```

[image]

These basically insert an invisible closing/opening (respectively) delimeter, so that you always have a pair. A `\left` must be paired with a `\right`, but obviously you don't always want an actual delimeter printed, so we have `\right.` and `\left.`.

Or you can use manually sized brackets, e.g. `\bigl( ... \bigr)`

Or you can just use normal brackets. Certainly, `\left( ... \right)` is not necessary here and overusing these can cause you problems, see:

["(" or "\left(" parentheses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/or-left-parentheses)

[Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right?lq=1)

Comment: Many thanks! It worked for me.  And A,B.C were just generic letterings I used to represent the quantities actually appearing in my equation.

Comment: @CAF Ah, in that case, fair enough. But it is common for people (with the best of intentions) to overuse `\left( ... \right)`, thinking it's giving them optimal scaling every time and we have a number of questions on this site where people would like them to be used by default. But, in fact, they should be used only where necessary and sometimes it's better to use manual sizing, like I say, if you do need a bigger delimeter

Comment: Ok thanks for the comments and the quick reply! +1, accepted

Comment: actually, `equation` would be better here than `align`.  since there's only one point of alignment, `split` takes care of that`, and there's only a single numbered expression, which is equivalent to a one-liner.