# Lower a constraint in the formula

Tags: math-mode

How can I add the term v<-{0,1}^n to the formula as in the screenshot?

```
   $  Pr_{v \leftarrow {0,1}^n} [ Fre(A,B,C) = Ja ] \leq \frac{1}{2} $
```

[image]

**Edit Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ amssymb }

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[1.] $\underset{v \leftarrow {0,1}^n}{\Pr} \Big[ \texttt{Fre}(A,B,C) = \texttt{Ja} \Big] \leq \frac{1}{2}$

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code you've posted under the **Edit Code:** line won't compile unless one replaces `\usepackage{ amssymb }` with `\usepackage{ amsmath }`. (The macro `\underset` is provided by the `amsmath` package.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example (some tuning is needed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
  \Pr_{v \leftarrow \{0,1\}^n}[ \operatorname{Fre}(A,B,C) =\operatorname{Ja} ] \leq \frac{1}{2} 
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

If `Fre` and `Ja` are used more times, it would be wise to define them, e.g., `\newcommand{\Fre}{\operatorname{Fre}}`.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use the `\Pr` macro, which places its subscript argument (the "constraint") *below* rather than to the side when in displaystyle-math mode. For inline-style math mode, add `\limits` after `\Pr`.

A separate issue: use `\mathtt` for the letters that apparently need to be set in monospaced (aka "teletype") font face.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
inline-style math: use \texttt{\string\limits}&
$
\Pr\limits_{v\gets\{0,1\}^n} [ \mathtt{Fre}(A,B,C) = \mathtt{Ja} ] \leq \frac{1}{2} .
$ \\[3ex]
display-style math &
$\displaystyle
\Pr_{v\gets\{0,1\}^n} [ \mathtt{Fre}(A,B,C) = \mathtt{Ja} ] \leq \frac{1}{2} .
$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Przemysław's solution would be to use `\underset{•}{•}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\underset{v \leftarrow \left\{0,1\right\}^n}{\Pr} \Big[ \texttt{Fre}(A,B,C) = \texttt{Ja} \Big] \leq \frac{1}{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

I also tuned your original formula a bit to make it look a bit nicer.

[image: formula]

Comment: I am trying to put it as item but I am getting this error `! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \underset l.8 \item[1.] $\underset` in the edit code. Do u know how can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, that you need the `amsmath` package.

Comment: The `\left` and `\right` modifiers to `\{` and `\}` aren't needed. In fact, they do exactly nothing but produce code clutter.

Comment: @Mico You are right. It's just a habit of mine, that I add `\left` and `\right` all the time, so I don't forget it when it is actually needed.

Comment: Please check out the postings [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/5001) and [“(” or “\left(” parentheses?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12773/5001) for discussions of why using `\left` and `\right` habitually can be quite counterproductive.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for making me aware of these questions.