# How to prevent \vec from making \left(\vec{f}\right) ugly?

Tags: spacing, vector

It seems like `\vec` makes `\left(` and `\right)` expand in an ugly fashion:

```
\begin{align*}
    \ g(\vec{f})
    \ g\!\left(\dot{f}\right)
    \ g\!\left(\dot{\vec{f}}\right)
    \ g\!\left(\vec{f}\right)
    \ g\!\left(f^2\right)
    \ g\!\left(\dot{f}^2\right)
    \ g\!\left(\vec{f}^2\right)
    \ g\!\left(\vec{f}\right)
    \ g\!\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right)
    \ g\!\left(\frac{\partial \vec{f}}{\partial t}\right)
\end{align*}
```

What happens is that there is too much whitespace underneath the letter, which is rather... jarring.

Interestingly, while `\dot`, etc. do the same thing, superscripts don't.

How can I prevent this from happening given that I need to use `\left(` and `\right)`?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Just use `g(\vec{f}\,)` Fine spacing is often necessary when coping with clashing symbols.

Answer (score 4):

You start from the wrong assumption that the parentheses should vertically cover the whole symbol. It's not so: some overshooting doesn't hinder reading and understanding the meaning.

When `\vec` is involved (which I consider an inherently flawed notation, but that's not under discussion), some fine adjustments are necessary if a prime or a parenthesis follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
g(\vec{f}\,)
\quad
g(\dot{\vec{f}}\,)
\quad
g\bigl(\dot{\vec{f}}\,\,\bigr)
\quad
g\biggl(\frac{\partial\vec{f}}{\partial x}\,\biggr)
\quad
g\biggl(\frac{\partial\dot{\vec{f}}}{\partial x}\,\biggr)
\]
\end{document}
```

Don't use `\left` and `\right` in these cases: as you clearly saw, they choose the wrong size for the delimiters.

[image]

Here's a way with `\left` and `\right`; not that I can recommend it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}

\mleftright % fix the bad spacing of \left and \right

\begin{document}
The following is mostly a joke
\[
\left(
  \vphantom{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}
  \frac{\smash[t]{\partial\vec{f}}}{\partial x}\,
\right)
\vphantom{\frac{\partial\vec{f}}{\partial x}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this isn't an answer to my question though. I *specifically* said **given that I need to use `\left` and `\right`**. The whole point of my question is to let the system auto-size and prevent `\vec` from affecting the sizing, just as how a superscript doesn't affect the auto-sizing. I also never made that assumption... I'm perfectly fine with a `\vec` that doesn't cause the parentheses to cover the whole symbol (in fact, that's basically what I'm asking for).

Comment: @Mehrdad What I wanted to say is that you *can't* get good results with `\left` and `\right`. You could `\smash` the letter with `\vec`, but this will just shift the problem to line spacing.

Comment: Oh, interesting... is there no way to e.g. make the `\vec` "float" in some sense, so that it's there but doesn't take up space? Edit: just saw your edit, I see.

Comment: Funny enough, `\smash` seems to do exactly what I want at least for non-inline math when line spacing isn't an issue. I imagine some combination with `\phantom` might do the job in some other cases. You should put that in your answer!

Comment: @egreg on a related note: do you have any advise on the placement of the arrow? To me the vector on f is too much to the right (have that problem in a manuscript I'm editing, I hacked something ugly and wonders if there us a better solution)

Comment: @daleif: Wow, I hadn't even noticed until you pointed it out now... and now I can't un-see it -.- thanks :P

Comment: @daleif Probably something like `{\mspace{1.5mu}\vec{\mspace{-1.5mu}f}}`

Comment: @egreg: By the way, why do people hate `\left` and `\right` so much? I feel like every time I've asked a question about how to do something with those two commands, the first answer I've received has been to not use them. Do you know why...?

Comment: @egreg that was sort of what I'm doing. Mspace is that just mkern in cosplay?

Comment: @mehrdad mostly because they so often get a little or a lot too big. I usually go by this rule: it should be clear for the reader what is being fenced in. But the fences should not become the focal point

Comment: @daleif Yes, `\mspace` is defined by `amsmath` in analogy with `\hspace`; it is `\mskip` in disguise.

Comment: @egreg interesting, never seen it before

Comment: @Mehrdad - "Why do people hate \left and \right so much?" Check out the postings [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/5001) and [“(” or “\left(” parentheses?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12773/5001) for information on why using `\left` and `\right` indiscriminately can lead to undesirable typographic outcomes.