# Is there a parenthesis with a size inbetween the default size and that of "\big("?

Tags: parenthesis

I'm using the standard packages - amsmath, amssymb, amsthm.

`\big(` is too big while simply `(` is too small. Is there a nice way to get something in between?

Comment: Which math font family do you use?

Comment: Regular (computer modern)

Comment: Hmmm, I find that with Computer Modern, `\big(` is only slightly bigger than `(`. Are you maybe using `\Big(`?

Comment: No I checked. I think I'm just being very fussy. But then again, LaTeX's flexibility is great, so why not continue being fussy!

Comment: can you show us an example of what you're getting (and code that shows how you got it)?  computer modern doesn't have any intermediate size between "normal text size" and `\big`.

Comment: I would say that it is a big advantage not to have too many sizes to choose from. -that way your parenthesis will be consistent(match the size of nearby others) throughout the document.

Answer (score 2):

Probably \left( and \right) do a convenient height adjustment.

Comment: Not at all. Not at all. Not at all.

Comment: The `\left(` and similar are famous for *not* being the correct size. I am pretty sure, that most people writing serious math select the size manually. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12793/8650