# Pandoc refuses to parse math latex

Tags: math-mode, pandoc

I have a markdown file like:

```
blah blah $|\left<R_j^{(x)},g_j^{(x)}\right>|$ blah
```

I tried to use Pandoc to convert this file into a `.docx` file, but it cannot recognise the math expression surrounded by dollar sign `'$'`. The math content appears in the output `.docx` file as raw (or verbatim) text.

However, the another file that contains a different math expression, like:

```
blah blah $\min _{ \omega _{ j }^{ (x) } } \left\| x-\sum _{ j=0 }^{ p-1 }{\omega^{(x)}_j g_{ d\gamma _{ d }j }^{ (x) } }  \right\|$
```

was handled well by Pandoc.
Is it because that I've done something wrong in my first markdown file? 
Or it is just a bug in Pandoc? How can I avoid it?

My Pandocversion is:

> pandoc 1.17.1
>   Compiled with texmath 0.8.6.3, highlighting-kate 0.6.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `<`...`>` as the delimiters, you need to use `\langle`...`\rangle`:

```
blah blah $|\left\langle R_j^{(x)},g_j^{(x)}\right\rangle|$ blah
```

Comment: The use of `\left`...`\right` in the example doesn't seem needed at all.

Comment: To avoid future confusion that I may encounter, would you please explain the difference between `<` ... `>` pair and `\langle` ... `\rangle`? because i created those expressions by using an online equation generation tool, and at that time everything seems good. BTW. thanks for your answering and modification.

Comment: I've did some research then, this tex [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/or-left-parentheses) mentioned the `\left<`...`\right>` pair, however it cannot be used in pandoc.

Comment: @wangkaibule: Fundamentally TeX is different from Word in many respects, period. However, "[b]ecause Pandoc’s intermediate representation of a document is less expressive than many of the formats it converts between, one should not expect perfect conversions between every format and every other." Perhaps one could [file a feature request](http://pandoc.org/CONTRIBUTING.html) to automatically change `\left<`...`\right>` into `\left\langle`...`\right\rangle` for conversion-to-Word purposes.