# How can I simplify this equation?

Tags: equations, align

I want to write the following word equation in Latex: 
[image]

I have the following codes:

```
\begin{align}                  
\mathbf {P_{t} &= \sum_{j=1}^{\rho } \left ( I - G_{0} \right )^{-1} \left [ D_{j} + D_{0}  \left ( I - G_{0} \right )^{-1} B_{j}\right ] Y_{t-j} + \sum_{j=1}^{\rho } \left ( I - G_{0} \right )^{-1} \left [ G_{j} + D_{0}  \left ( I - B_{0} \right )^{-1} C_{j}\right ] P_{t-j} \nonumber \\
               &\hphantom{=} + \sum_{j=1}^{\rho } \left ( I - G_{0} \right )^{-1} \left [ G_{j} + D_{0}  \left ( I - B_{0} \right )^{-1} C_{j}\right ] P_{t-j} \nonumber \\
               &\hphantom{=}  + B_{j} Y_{t-j} + \left ( I - G_{0} \right )^{-1} D_{0} \left ( I - B_{0} \right )^{-1}A^{y} v_{t}^{y} + u_{p}^{t}}, \label{eqn:{2}'}                  
\end{align}
```

I was trying to break it up using `\nonumber \\` and  `&\hphantom{=}` but it is just not working. I am getting some errors. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Note this my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}

% Packages
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
    \rel@kern{0.8}%
    \overline{\rel@kern{-0.8}\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.2}}%
    \rel@kern{-0.2}%
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
  \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{natbib}
%\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{;}{,}{,}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
  linkcolor=blue
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{forest}
\captionsetup{labelfont=normalfont,
              labelsep=colon}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning}
%
\tikzset{
    full/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=0, minimum size=1mm,fill=black},
    every node/.style={minimum height=5mm,font=\footnotesize}
}
%
\makeatletter
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{1}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\itshape}}
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \edef\@toclevel{\ifnum#2=\@m 0\else\number#2\fi}%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \let\@secnumber\@empty
  \else \@xp\let\@xp\@secnumber\csname the#1\endcsname\fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \edef\@secnumpunct{%
      \ifdim\@tempskipa>\z@ % not a run-in section heading
        \@ifnotempty{#8}{.\@nx\enspace}%
      \else
        \@ifempty{#8}{.}{.\@nx\enspace}%
      \fi
    }%
    \@ifempty{#8}{%
      \ifnum #2=\tw@ \def\@secnumfont{\bfseries}\fi}{}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{%
      \ifnum#2<\@m
        \@ifundefined{#1name}{}{%
          \ignorespaces\csname #1name\endcsname\space
        }%
      \fi
      \@seccntformat{#1}%
    }%
  \fi
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@ % then this is not a run-in section heading
    \begingroup #6\relax
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}{\interlinepenalty\@M #8\par}%
    \endgroup
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  \else
  \def\@svsechd{#6\hskip #3\@svsec
    \@ifnotempty{#8}{\ignorespaces#8\unskip
       %\@addpunct.
       }%
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  }%
  \fi
  \global\@nobreaktrue
  \@xsect{#5}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{plain}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{12pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\allowdisplaybreaks[4]
% Commenting/debugging
\let\IG\iffalse
\let\ENDIG\fi

%% Shortcuts
\newcommand{\td}[2]{\dfrac{d #1}{d #2}}
\newcommand{\std}[2]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\ctd}[3]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d #2 d #3}}

\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\spd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\cpd}[3]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial #2 \partial #3}}

\newcommand{\pdi}[2]{\partial #1/\partial #2}

\newcommand{\LR}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Lg}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\half}{\tfrac{1}{2}}
\newcommand{\eqp}{\phantom{=}}
\newcommand{\eqs}{\buildrel s \over =}
\newcommand{\me}{\mathrm{e}}
%begin codes for footnotes (symbols)
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myfnsymbolsingle}[1]{%
    \ensuremath{%
        \ifcase#1% 0
        \or % 1
        \dagger%   
        \or % 2
        1 
        \or % 3  
        2
        \or % 4   
        3
        \or % 5
        4
        \else % >= 6
        \@ctrerr  
        \fi
    }%   
}      
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myfnsymbol}[1]{%
  \myfnsymbolsingle{\value{#1}}%
}

% remove upper boundary by multiplying the symbols if needed
\usepackage{alphalph}
\newalphalph{\myfnsymbolmult}[mult]{\myfnsymbolsingle}{}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{%
  \myfnsymbolmult{\value{footnote}}%
}
%end codes for footnotes (symbols)
```

Comment: I hate to be a bore, but I really would ask you to review the [tips for creating a good MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), especially in light of comments on another recent question of yours. Your code is, again, extremely bloated and unhelpful - and the person that's most unhelpful to is you! It needs to go on a diet ;)

Comment: this has just a single equation number, so why not just use `\begin{split} ... \end{split}` within an `equation`?  that's what it's for.

Comment: @barbarabeeton In principle that's the neatest idea and it's what I tried first when writing my answer, but I completely changed tack, because the different line heights of each line means the equation label (which is rightly vertically centred) is not in line with any of the lines of the equation. I didn't like this effect as much, so I numbered it manually instead

Comment: @Au101 -- to my eyes, there's too much "air" between the first and second lines.  i'd be tempted to try `\smash`ing the bottom of (only) the sum-component on the first line, regardless of how the numbering is applied.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Added as an option :)

Comment: @Au101 Since it's a single block, I see no need that the number is aligned to one of the rows, unless it's the last/first (tbtags option)

Comment: @egreg I certainly agree that there's no need, I just didn't like it, I thought it looked a little skew-whiff, but there's no accounting for taste :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{2}

\begin{align}
  \mathbf{P}_{t} = \sum_{j = 1}^{\rho} (\mathbf{I} &-
  \mathbf{G}_{0})^{-1} [\mathbf{D}_{j} + \mathbf{D}_{0} (\mathbf{I} -
  \mathbf{B}_{0})^{-1} \mathbf{B}_{j}] \mathbf{Y}_{t - j} \nonumber
  \\
  &+ \sum_{j = 1}^{\rho} (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{G}_{0})^{-1}
  [\mathbf{G}_{j} + \mathbf{D}_{0} (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{B}_{0})^{-1}
  \mathbf{C}_{j}] \mathbf{P}_{t - j} \tag{\theequation$'$} \\
  &+ (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{G}_{0})^{-1} \mathbf{D}_{0} (\mathbf{I} -
  \mathbf{B}_{0})^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{y} \mathbf{v}_{t}^{y} +
  \mathbf{u}_{t}^{p}, \nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Done simply with a `\nonumber` command before the `\\` of the first line, a `\tag` command before the `\\` of the second line and a final `\nonumber` at the end of the last line, using the `align` environment.

Also, you might like to consider using `\smash[b]{...}` (as recommended by [barbara beeton in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319489/how-can-i-simplify-this-equation?noredirect=1#comment780440_319489)) to tighten up the equation and remove that considerable chasm. Whatever you think looks best:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{2}

\begin{align}
  \mathbf{P}_{t} = \smash[b]{\sum_{j = 1}^{\rho}} (\mathbf{I} &-
  \mathbf{G}_{0})^{-1} [\mathbf{D}_{j} + \mathbf{D}_{0} (\mathbf{I} -
  \mathbf{B}_{0})^{-1} \mathbf{B}_{j}] \mathbf{Y}_{t - j} \nonumber
  \\
  &+ \sum_{j = 1}^{\rho} (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{G}_{0})^{-1}
  [\mathbf{G}_{j} + \mathbf{D}_{0} (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{B}_{0})^{-1}
  \mathbf{C}_{j}] \mathbf{P}_{t - j} \tag{\theequation$'$} \\
  &+ (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{G}_{0})^{-1} \mathbf{D}_{0} (\mathbf{I} -
  \mathbf{B}_{0})^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{y} \mathbf{v}_{t}^{y} +
  \mathbf{u}_{t}^{p}, \nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative with `split`, where lines are “equalized” by smashing the summation symbols and inserting a vertical phantom:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{2}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\vphantom{\Bigg|}
\bv{P}_{t} =
  \smash{\sum_{j = 1}^{\rho}}
  (\bv{I} &- \bv{G}_{0})^{-1}
    [\bv{D}_{j} + \bv{D}_{0} (\bv{I} - \bv{B}_{0})^{-1} \bv{B}_{j}] \bv{Y}_{t - j}
\vphantom{\Bigg|}
  \\
  &+ \smash{\sum_{j = 1}^{\rho}} (\bv{I} - \bv{G}_{0})^{-1}
    [\bv{G}_{j} + \bv{D}_{0} (\bv{I} - \bv{B}_{0})^{-1}
    \bv{C}_{j}] \bv{P}_{t - j}
  \\
\vphantom{\Bigg|}
  &+ (\bv{I} - \bv{G}_{0})^{-1} \bv{D}_{0} (\bv{I} -
    \bv{B}_{0})^{-1} \bv{A}_{\vphantom{t}}^{y} \bv{v}_{t}^{y} + \bv{u}_{t}^{p},
\end{split}
\tag{\theequation$'$}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, some advice, please avoid using `\left` and `\right` **unless you need them**, see for example:

- [Question
  1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right?noredirect=1&lq=1),
- And [Question
  2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/or-left-parentheses).

Comment: Nitpicking: `\mathbf{A}_{\vphantom{t}}^{y}` in the last line

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a variant on your second solution

Comment: Thank you @egreg, it does look very nice that way, I'm sure your approach would have stood very well as an answer on its own and by all means feel free to post it, but thanks for the extra help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{1}
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}$'$}
\begin{align}
\mathbf {\mathbf{P}}_{t} =& \sum_{j=1}^{\rho } \left ( {\mathbf{I}} - {\mathbf{G}}_{0} \right )^{-1} \left [ {\mathbf{D}}_{j} + {\mathbf{D}}_{0}  \left ( {\mathbf{I}} - {\mathbf{B}}_{0} \right )^{-1} {\mathbf{B}}_{j}\right ] Y_{t-j}\nonumber\\
               &\quad+ \sum_{j=1}^{\rho } \left ( {\mathbf{I}} - {\mathbf{G}}_{0} \right )^{-1} \left [ {\mathbf{G}}_{j} + {\mathbf{D}}_{0}  \left ( {\mathbf{I}} - {\mathbf{B}}_{0} \right )^{-1} {\mathbf{C}}_{j}\right ] {\mathbf{P}}_{t-j} \nonumber \\
               &\quad+ \left ( {\mathbf{I}} - {\mathbf{G}}_{0} \right )^{-1} {\mathbf{D}}_{0} \left ( {\mathbf{I}} - {\mathbf{B}}_{0} \right )^{-1}{\mathbf{A}}^{y} {\mathbf{v}}_{t}^{y} + {\mathbf{u}}^{p}_{t}, \label{eqn:{2}'}
\end{align} 

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I propose two other solutions: one with `multline`, the other with `align` and an alignment of the equation number *between* the second and last line, as in the image of the question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array, mathtools}

\newtagform{prime}{(}{$'$)}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{1}
\usetagform{prime}
\begin{multline}
  \mathbf{P}_{t} ={∑_{j = 1}^{ρ}} (\mathbf{I}- \mathbf{G}_{0})⁻¹ [\mathbf{D}_{j} + \mathbf{D}_{0} (\mathbf{I} -
  \mathbf{B}_{0})⁻¹ \mathbf{B}_{j}] \mathbf{Y}_{t - j}
  \\[-3ex]
  + {∑_{j = 1}^{ρ}} (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{G}_{0})⁻¹
  [\mathbf{G}_{j} + \mathbf{D}_{0} (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{B}_{0})⁻¹
    \mathbf{C}_{j}] \mathbf{P}_{t - j} \\[-1.5ex]
    + {}(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{G}_{0})⁻¹ \mathbf{D}_{0} (\mathbf{I} -
    \mathbf{B}_{0})⁻¹ \mathbf{A}^{y} \mathbf{v}_{t}^{y} +   \mathbf{u}_{t}^{p},
  \end{multline}


  \begin{align}
    \mathbf{P}_{t} ={∑_{j = 1}^{ρ}}(\mathbf{I} & - \mathbf{G}_{0})⁻¹ [\mathbf{D}_{j} + \mathbf{D}_{0} (\mathbf{I} -
    \mathbf{B}_{0})⁻¹ \mathbf{B}_{j}] \mathbf{Y}_{t - j} \notag
    \\[-0.5ex]
                                                     & \begin{array}{@{} >{\displaystyle}l@{}}
    {}+ \smash[t]{∑_{j = 1}^{ρ}} (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{G}_{0})⁻¹
    [\mathbf{G}_{j} + \mathbf{D}_{0} (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{B}_{0})⁻¹
    \mathbf{C}_{j}] \mathbf{P}_{t - j} \\
    \phantom{\sum}  +  (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{G}_{0})⁻¹ \mathbf{D}_{0} (\mathbf{I} -
    \mathbf{B}_{0})⁻¹ \mathbf{A}^{y} \mathbf{v}_{t}^{y} +
    \mathbf{u}_{t}^{p},
    \end{array}
  \end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What about helping yourself with a macro:

```
\newcomand{\foo}[2][]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#2}_{#1}}}
```

used in @Jagath AR's answer

```
\begin{align}
  \foo P[t]=\sum_{j=1}^\rho (\foo I-\foo G[0])^{-1} ... \nonumber
  & ... \nonumber
  & ... \foo A^y\foo v[t]^y+\foo u[t]^p
\end{align}
```

Comment: What's `\ensuremath` for?

Comment: If you want to use the command outside `math` or `displaymath` environment.

Comment: Why would you? Just to clutter your typescript? `;-)` Using `$\foo{A}$` when the variable is in the text is much clearer and not more difficult to type.

Comment: I'd prefer `\( \foo A\)` and for sentences full of variables I'm sometimes getting lost...