# Missing \right ]

Tags: math-mode, errors

I try to write [Lavecchia et al., 2007] in a footnote like this in latex :

```
$\left[$Lavecchia et al., 2007$\right]$}
```

But I get an error :

> Missing \right  inserted

And I get only

> [Lavecchia et al., 2007

as a result

any idea please?

thank you

Comment: A `\left` must always be followed by a `\right` , and followed means it has to be within the same pair of `$ ... $`, in the same environment, on the same line, etc. etc. But yes this is an abuse of math mode, it's also an abuse of `\left` and `\right`, you should be very careful about overusing these, they are certainly not necessary here. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right?noredirect=1&lq=1 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/or-left-parentheses

Comment: Entering math mode is not a sensible way to make citations!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\left` and `\right` should *only* be used in the context of mathematics -- this is textual. Just say `[Lavecchia et al., 2007]` (or better yet use a reference management system like BibLaTeX -- several compatible GUI options exist as well).

The error is happening because when `\left` is used in the first entrance into math mode, there's no corresponding `\right` (and similarly with the second entrance).