# Horizontal placement of subscript/superscript

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

I want to fine-tune the placement of subscripts and superscripts next to large parentheses. Since the large parentheses bulge out, they push the sub/superscripts too far to the right. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[ \left(\frac{1}{2}A + B\right)_2 \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Large parentheses push subscript too far to the right]

Is there a way to fine-tune this? Just to nudge the 2 over a bit? I'm using pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just avoid `\left` and `\right`. They add nothing and actually do harm. If you really need larger parentheses, for this case use `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`.

Comment: Although in this case larger parentheses are not indicated. I mean as a matter of taste you're free to do whatever you like, but there is no need of large parentheses here, you're creating a problem you don't need. If you really want a visual contrast to the brackets around the arguments of the function, why not consider using square brackets?

Comment: Toatally agree that such large parenthesis in this case are not needed.  But, to nudge the subscripts, you can apply a negative thin space: So instead of `_2` use `_{\!2}` or  `_{\!\!2}`.  Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Anyway, I *don't* get those humongous parentheses with your code in a standard document. Please, make a real example.

Comment: @egreg Updated to include MWE, thanks. Why are `\left` and `\ right` bad?

Comment: @DavidM. Not in this case, of course. But it's normal that, when the parenthesis becomes very large, you need `\!` to nudge the subscript or superscript. I always do it.

Comment: @DavidM. - For discussions of why it can be suboptimal to use `\left` and `\right` see, e.g., [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/5001) and [“(” or “\left(” parentheses?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12773/5001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could "nudge" the subscript to the left, i.e., place it closer to the closing parenthesis, by writing `_{\!\!2}` (two negative thinspaces) or `_{\!2}` (one negative thinspace) instead of just `_2`. Even better, though, would be not to use `\left` and `\right` to auto-size the parentheses to begin with. In fact,  `\left` and `\right` may be the root cause of the problem, since the parentheses that are produced by `\left(` and `\right)` are needlessly large. Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

The first row is produced by your code, i.e., by `\left(\frac{1}{2}A + B\right)_2`. The second row shows the effect of nudging the subscript to the left via `_{\!\!2}`. In the third row, `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` are used instead of `\left` and `\right`; here, much less "nudging" is required.

The final row uses `\tfrac` ("text style `\frac`") to create a smaller, but still perfectly readable fraction term along with `\bigl` and `\bigr`. Now, no nudging is required *at all*. I would argue that the expression in the final row is the most readable of the four. :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather*' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \left(\frac{1}{2}A + B\right)_2 \\
  \left(\frac{1}{2}A + B\right)_{\!\!2}\\
  \Bigl(\frac{1}{2}A+B\Bigr)_{\!2}\\
  \bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}A+B\bigr)_2
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```