# Superscript in subscript (notation for removing one row and column from a matrix)

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

I need some notation for a matrix *M* which indicates that row *r* and column *c* is excluded.  I tried

```
M_{(r,c)^-}
```

but the minus sign is too low and not close enough for this to be good notation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
M_{(r,c)^-}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here are some proposals which I don't know how to do in LaTeX:

- Move the minus sign to be a little higher and closer to the close bracket and maybe a little smaller.
- Forget the minus  sign but use a bracket which is not (), [] or {}.

Comment: Note that MathJax is not enabled on the site. I added some minimal code and the result. I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. I just don't like the notation in the end. I was hoping for suggestions.

Comment: I'm afraid that as posed the question is off-topic. It can become a good question if you make some proposals and ask about *how* to realize them with LaTeX.

Comment: @egreg Understood. I added some specific questions of this sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to modify the position of the superscript. From [{(x+y)}^2 or (x+y)^2?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104004/xy2-or-xy2), [Horizontal placement of subscript/superscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359524/horizontal-placement-of-subscript-superscript), [How to raise a subscript?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5191/how-to-raise-a-subscript):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$M_{(r,c)^-}$
$M_{{(r,c)}^-}$       % lowers the subscript
$M_{{(r,c)}^{\!-}}$   % horizontal position
$M_{(r,c)}${\raisebox{0.5pt}{${}^{\!\!\!-}$}}  % vertical position
\end{document}
```

[image]