# Use of \left[...\middle]+\midle[...\right]

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I try to modify @Mico [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360685/integration-brackets-are-not-tall-enough) as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
V = \int_0^2(4-x^2)\,dx
= 4\int_0^2\!dx - \int_0^2\!x^2\,dx
= 4\left[x\middle]_0^2 - \middle[\frac{1}{3}x^3\right]_0^2
\]
\end{document}
```

but to my surprise I got the following result:

[image]

Is this a bug?

I expect that at both term indices will be on the same position regarding bracket. The same result is also if instead `x` is for example if in brackets is `\frac{1}{x}`.

Comment: `\middle` isn't as useful as one might have hoped....

Comment: Why would you use `\middle` for this? Anyway, `\middle` is `\left` under cover, so it doesn't accept subscript or superscript.

Comment: thank you for finding duplicate and explanations. now, after this, the purpose of `\middle` is not clear anymore to me :(