# Same spacing around "\middle|" as around "\mid"

Tags: math-mode, spacing, delimiters, parentheses

I need to write some equations that contain something like `(A | B)`.

I could write `\left( A \middle| \right)`, but this changes spacing around external parentheses, as expained in many topics like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427443/).

There is a nice working solution with `\DeclarePairedLimiterX` as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124781/156704). However, for many reasons I would like to use `\middle|` and fix the spacing around it (so that it is the same as around `\mid`), in the same way as `\left` and `\right` are fixed in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2614/156704) or by the package `mleftright` (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427673/156704)). In other words, I would like `|` to stretch like `\middle|` and to have the same spacing as `\mid`. Is it possible? I'm using `mathtools`.

Thank you!

Comment: Honestly, I've always just used the lazy solution: `\,\middle|\,`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An engine-independent solution (albeit one I still have a murky feeling about...)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\let\originalmiddle=\middle
\def\middle#1{\mathrel{}\originalmiddle#1\mathrel{}}

\begin{document}

\[
(A \mid B)
\left(A \middle| B\right)
\left(\frac{A}{B} \middle\Vert C_{(A \mid B) \left( A \middle| B \right)} \right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. And it works with LuaLaTeX too, not just pdfLaTeX...

Comment: @Mico Well, yes, I meant that Henri's solution depends on lua code while this one doesn't. I'll rephrase.

Comment: Thank you, very simple and also similar to the fixes I used for left and right

Comment: @Taekwondavide Maybe instead of redefining `\middle` (I'm always cautious about redefining `TeX` primitives) you might want to define something like `\mmiddle` (like `\mleft`/`\mright`).

Comment: Thank you. I'm considering that, I'm still in doubt about using redefined `\middle` and `\originalmiddle` or `\mmiddle` and original `\middle`. I guess I have to check whether any package is using `\middle` or not

Answer (score 5):

You can use some Lua magic.

The three snippets below are one file.  They are only split up because Stack Exchange does not support mixed highlighting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
local noad_id = node.id("noad")
local fence_id = node.id("fence")
local inner_subtype = 9 -- see texnodes.w
local middle_subtype = 2 -- see texnodes.w

local function is_vert(delim)
    return delim.small_fam == 2
        and delim.small_char == 106
        and delim.large_fam == 3
        and delim.large_char == 12
end

local kern = node.new("kern",99) -- 99 = math kern
kern.kern = 5 * 2^16 -- 5 pt (TODO: load this value from the font)

local function adjust_mid_spacing(head)
    for n in node.traverse(head) do
        if n and n.nucleus and n.nucleus.head then
            adjust_mid_spacing(n.nucleus.head)
        elseif n.id == fence_id and n.subtype == middle_subtype then
            if is_vert(n.delim) then
                node.insert_before(head,n,node.copy(kern))
                node.insert_after(head,n,node.copy(kern))
            end
        end
    end
    return head
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("mlist_to_hlist",
                           function(head, display_type, need_penalties)
                               head = adjust_mid_spacing(head)
                               return node.mlist_to_hlist(head, display_type, need_penalties)
                           end,
                           "adjust spacing around mid")
```

```
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

$\left( A \middle| B \right)_{\left( A \middle| B \right)_{\left( A \middle| B \right)}}$

$(A \mid B)_{(A \mid B)_{(A \mid B)}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it's simpler in luatex (Umiddle class 2)

Answer (score 5):

luatex allows the mathclass to be specified on delimiters and you want 2 (mathbin) here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


$\left( A \middle| B \right)$



$\Uleft( A \Umiddle class 2 | B \Uright)$



\end{document}
```

Comment: the spacing looks off to me and if you omit the B you get a "this can't happen" error and no output, but I expect those issues will get fixed, luatex is under very active development.

Comment: Cool. Wouldn't mathrel be more appropriate here though? I think `\mid` has class 3.

Comment: @Circumscribe possibly (I think spacing is a bit wrong for that as well so it's not too important at the moment which you pick:-)

Comment: Thank you! I don't know luatex, is it 100% compatible with latex and texlive/miktex?

Comment: luatex is included in both texlive and miktex as an alternative to pdftex, it is not 100% compatible. Like xetex it uses (mostly) Unicode fonts installed in the system rather than specific tex-encoded fonts, however most latex documents can be used with xelatex or lualatex with small changes, we have answers on this site giving the differences @Taekwondavide