# LuaLaTeX and \big, \bigg, \Big, \Bigg: Change the math class of the symbol (i.e. change spacing)

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, delimiters

I am referring to [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431825/47156) to the question on how one can achieve the same spacing around `\middle|` as around `\mid`. Please note, that I am using `unicode-math` and LuaLaTeX.

The answer is to use the unicode versions `\Uleft`, `\Umiddle` and `\Uright` and state the class explicitly, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\Uleft( A \Umiddle class 2 | B \Uright)$
\end{document}
```

Now, I have

```
\renewcommand{\left}{\Uleft}
\renewcommand{\right}{\Uright}
\renewcommand{\middle}{\Umiddle class 2 }
```

after `\begin{document}` and I am quite happy with the spacing.

However, sometimes I need to resort to the explicit sizes `\big`, `\bigg`, ... and so on and their respective left and right counterparts. My naive hope was that their are also unicode variants and `\Ubig class 2 \vert` would do the trick. But those commands do not exist.

How do I get a class-2 spacing for `\big`,  `\bigg`, ... and so on?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Doesn't `\biggm|` (or `\biggm\vert`) work out to the same as `\mathrel{\bigg|}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you want a class 2 (`\mathbin`)  `\Big` `|` you can simply use

```
 a  \mathbin{\Big|}  b
```

which would work in luatex as in pdftex.

for class3 (`\mathrel`) latex already defines `\Bigm`.

Comment: OK. Actually, I hoped for an answer which would allow me to redefine `\big`, ... and so on once in the beginning of the document such that I do not need scan for all occurrences in my document (its >300 pages). Unfortunately, the usual trick `\let\obig\big` and `\def\big#1{\mathbin{\obig #1}}` did not work, because `\bigl` is defined as `\mathopen\big` and than things go terrible wrong, because I end up with `\mathopen\mathbin` for `\bigl`. :-(

Comment: I thought `\Bigr` is of type `\mathclose` and not `\mathrel`? :-o

Comment: @nagmat84 `\let\foo=\big  \def\big{\mathbin\foo}`  should work

Comment: @nagmat84 Bigr -> Bigm fixed :-)