# how to adjust the bar in the notation for the derivative assigned in $s = 0$?

Tags: math-mode

How can I do this bar with the size adjusted?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Personnally, I would write$\vu(s)$ on the left of the vertical  line

Comment: I agree it looks better. I only put the print as it has written in the paper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- I use the `\left` and `\right` approach.
- With `\left.` you create an "empty" `\left`. See Equation 2 where I used `\left|` instead.
- With `\right|` you create the bar that you want.
- Equation 3 is just a typographical addition and un-related to the question (`\text{d}` instead of `d`). Some people prefer it that way.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

% amsmath + improvements (here used for \text in math mode)
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=0} \nu(s)
\end{equation}

Equation 2 ist just to show the effect of \texttt{\textbackslash left.} compared to \texttt{\textbackslash left|}.
\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=0} \nu(s)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left.\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}s}\right|_{s=0} \nu(s)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Further reading

- https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Brackets_and_Parentheses
- ["(" or "\left(" parentheses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773)
- [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717)

Answer (score 5):

Like this? (with amendments suggested by Manuel Kühner and egreg)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle 
 \frac{d}{ds}\bigg\vert_{s=0} \nu(s) \quad\mbox{or}\quad
 \frac{d\nu(s)}{ds}\bigg|_{s=0}      \quad\mbox{or}\quad
 \nu\mkern1mu'(0)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: I think that I have never used `\vert` before :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner `\bigg|` would do as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is preferable to `\nu'(0)`. But I'm a mathematician, you know…

Comment: @egreg Thanks! That's easy to remember.

Answer (score 5):

It is very simple with the `diffcoeff` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}

\begin{document}

\[ \diff{ν(s)}{s}[s=0]\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I add my answer using `derivative` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{derivative}
\begin{document}
\[\odv{\nu(s)}{s}_{s=0}\quad \text{ or } \odv*{\phantom{d}}{s}_{s=0}\nu(s)\]
\end{document}
```

This is the screenshot:

[image]

Using another package that it is not very used (for reason also of spacing), called `physics`, you can obtained this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
\[\eval{\dv{s}}_{s=0}\nu(s), \quad \eval{\dv{\nu(s)}{s}}_{s=0}\]
\end{document}
```

....and this is the output:

[image: a]