# Brackets with correct delimiters and automation

Tags: math-mode, brackets

According to [What is the correct way to do delimiters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1454/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-delimiters) the correct way of using brackets in math mode could be achieved by a macro like this:

```
\newcommand{\myLeft}{\mathopen{}\left}
```

I wonder if there is a way to automate it. What I mean is that I would like to be able to write a formula in math mode without using `\left` and `\right.` I would like to 'replace' all opening brackets in math mode by `\myLeft+bracket` and all closing brackets by `\right+bracket`. Is that possible? What arguments are against such an approach?

Comment: There is a [package](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/nath/nathguide.pdf) that attempts to do just this, but I would caution that automating to this level will usually end in unexpected results.  (What about the interval [0,1)?)

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36039/automatic-size-adjustment-for-nested-parentheses

Comment: Hi DaPhil. A tip: if you copy and paste the url of the question directly, the title will appear in your post.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve but `\mathopen\left` is a syntax error so that presumably is not the definition that you want.

Comment: Corrected it to `\mathopen{}\left`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/difference-between-big-and-bigl/1234#1234

Comment: The package seems to have a couple of problems e.g. biblatex. Also it seems that it changes so much that I can't use align environment in a known way. I think this is not a good option since it changes too much.

Comment: Is there a way of using `nath` and the `align` environment of the `amsmath` package?