# Can I make LyX automatically use 'smart' parentheses [\left( \right)] in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, lyx, brackets

When I type in math mode I always prefer to use the parentheses using
`\left` and `\right`.

Currently, I go into math mode and then press the button on the ribbon
that appears in this mode and creates these type of parentheses.

I would prefer that when I type in `(` or `)` it would automatically
insert `\left` or `\right` accordingly.

Is there a way to do so ? I would prefer a way that would not require
me to do it for each new document I start.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Automatic left and right commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1742/5764). The suggestion is to include the [`nath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/nath) in your LaTeX preamble (Document -> Settings... -> LaTeX preamble).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You shouldn't always use `\left( ..  \right)`, one reason being that the spacing is different. Try comparing `\sin(x)` and `\sin\left(x\right)`, you'll see that the latter has the wrong spacing. Also, in many cases no scaling is required, so using them is unnecessary. Related questions:

- ["(" or "\left(" parentheses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/or-left-parentheses)
- [Spacing around \left and \right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right/)
- [What is the correct way to do delimiters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1454/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-delimiters)
- [Macro for \left( and \right)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31526/macro-for-left-and-right/58641#58641)
- [Automatic left and right commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/automatic-left-and-right-commands) (mentioned by Werner in a comment)

Hence, it would be better to only use `\left\right` when needed, and LyX has a shortcut for inserting these: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>(</kbd>. That is, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, release both, press <kbd>(</kbd>.

If that is one keystroke too many, you could create a new shortcut, for example <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>(</kbd>, that inserts a `\left( \right)` pair. Tools --> Preferences --> Editing --> Shortcuts. Search for *math-delim* and you'll find the existing shortcut, double click it to change.

Comment: I agree, in many cases `\left(...\right)` is excessive, for example when used in inline math, `\left(...\right)` very often ends up being too tall, and thus mess with line spacing. As Torbjørn mentions, use when appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I also use LyX and I also prefer using `\left` and `\right` parentheses in most cases. There is a shortcut that I use instead of clicking the "Insert delimiters" button:

From inside math mode I type

- Alt-m ( to get a pair of parentheses,
- Alt-m [ to get a pair of brackets,
- Alt-m { to get a pair of braces,
- Alt-m | to get a pair of vertical bars, etc.

Unfortunately this shortcut (as much as I know) doesn't work for double vertical lines (used to denote norms).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also just make a shortcut that is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd>, as you would normally type a parenthesis, but now it will just automatically insert a smart parenthesis.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Could you expand your answer to explain how to achieve this?