# How to write an Equation with the Units aligned off right and adapted Bracket Heights around the Unit?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, siunitx, units

Assumed I have this **MWE** to align the units off right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\add@text{}
\newcommand\tagaddtext[1]{%
  \gdef\add@text{#1\gdef\add@text{}}}% 
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{%
  \maketag@@@{\llap{\add@text\qquad}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Unfortunately the bracket does not fit to the height of the unit.
The units exponent is already positioned above the upper edge of the bracket. :-(

\begin{equation}
    A = B + C       \tagaddtext{[\si{\square\meter}]}
\end{equation}

How can I change this behavior?



\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

---

**Description of the eyesore:**

As you can see the corresponding brackets do not automatically adapt to the height of the unit. The exponent is higher than the bracket.

How can I change that behavior, so that the brackets will automatically adjust to the height of the highest/lowest point of the unit?

Comment: You can use `\tagaddtext{$\left[\si{\square\meter}\right]$}`. But this is usually not recommended. The image you show is the correct behavior AFAIK.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Thanks a lot! Could I implement the brackets into the `\newcommand`-configuration already? So that I only have to write `\tagaddtext{\si{\square\meter}}` into the document text and the brackets will show up automatically?

Comment: @PeterGrill: Excuse me, one more question: Why is your approach usually not recommended? Is it faulty typography to increase the brackets size matching to the exponents?

Comment: The issues with `\left...\right` are discussed in [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/4301), [“(” or “\left(” parentheses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12773/4301), [What is the correct way to do delimiters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1454/4301) and [Difference between \big[ and \bigl[](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1232/4301).

Comment: @PeterGrill: Ah, I understand! Thank you very much for your help! I will stop using `\left[ ... \right]` now at all. I never tought about those spacing problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose  for what it's worth a work-around with `flalign` and an `\addunit` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\addunit}[1]{\mathllap{\left[\si{#1}\right]\quad}}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
 & & A & = B + C & & \addunit{\square\meter}
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I should stop using `\begin{equation}blabla\end{equation}`? Or better use `\begin{flalign}` inside of `\begin{equation}`?

Comment: If you want to use   `\addunit `, yes, use   `flalign` in the place of `equation` – `flalign` can't be used inside another math  environment, and `flaligned` does not exist.