# How do I change the spacing for math operators?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, math-operators

I have defined my own math operator (for displaying the order of certain function sequences--this is not the "normal" Big-O notation, though) by:

```
\newcommand{\order}[1]{\ensuremath{\operatorname{o}\left({#1}\right)}}
```

This leads to pretty strange spacing:

[image: strange spacing]

How can I resolve this? Is there a better way to specify the operator?

Comment: You mean the spacing between the “o” and the opening bracket?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, I think in general it is probably a better idea to use `\DeclareMathOperator` rather than a combination of `\newcommand` and `\operatorname`. That said, I think your problem is because you used `\left(`. It should be fixed if you insert `\mathopen{}` before the `\left(`. See also [Difference between \big[ and \bigl[](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/difference-between-big-and-bigl/1234#1234)

Comment: Thank you! I do not know why I did not use `\DeclareMathOperator` in the first place for this instance. The link about spacing is also quite helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use the spacing commands such as \mathleft for left punctuation, \mathright for right punctuation, \mathop for a "large" operator, \mathbin for a binary operator, \mathrel for a relation sign. Details on p. 75ff of Voß's [Mathmode.pdf](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf).

Comment: Do you mean `\mathopen` and `\mathclose`?