# align: using aligned within align troubles

Tags: align

I would like the first two pieces in `align` look as though they are the only two items in the `align` environment and the rest to align at the equals signs and separated by some space for the different equality.

Right now it compiles looking like:

[image]

So the first two I would like to align as such:

[image]

and the last equalities I would like to align as

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    \vec{x}_1(t) &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      x_1^{(1)}(t)\\
      x_2^{(1)}(t)
    \end{pmatrix} &&{}=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      X_1^{(1)}\cos(\omega_1t + \phi_1)\\
      r_1X_1^{(1)}\cos(\omega_1t + \phi_1)
    \end{pmatrix}\\
    \vec{x}_2(t) &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      x_1^{(2)}(t)\\
      x_2^{(2)}(t)
    \end{pmatrix} &&{}=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      X_1^{(2)}\cos(\omega_2t + \phi_2)\\
      r_2X_1^{(2)}\cos(\omega_2t + \phi_2)
    \end{pmatrix}\\
    r_1 &=
    \begin{aligned}
      \frac{3k - m\omega_1^2}{2k} && \qquad
      X_1^{(1)} &&{}= \frac{1}{r_2 - r_1}\bigg[(r_2x_1(0) - x_2(0))^2 +
      \frac{(-r_2\dot{x}_1(0) + \dot{x}_2(0))^2}{\omega_1^2}\bigg]^{1/2}
    \end{aligned}\\
    r_2 &=
    \begin{aligned}
      \frac{3k - m\omega_2^2}{2k} && \qquad
      X_1^{(2)} &&{}= \frac{1}{r_2 - r_1}\bigg[(-r_1x_1(0) + x_2(0))^2 +
      \frac{(r_1\dot{x}_1(0) - \dot{x}_2(0))^2}{\omega_2^2}\bigg]^{1/2}
    \end{aligned}\\
    \phi_1 &=
    \begin{aligned}
      \arctan\bigg[\frac{-r_2\dot{x}_1(0) + \dot{x}_2(0)}
      {\omega_1^2(r_2x_1(0) - x_2(0))}\bigg] && \qquad
      \phi_2 &&{}= \arctan\bigg[\frac{r_1\dot{x}_1(0) - \dot{x}_2(0)}
      {\omega_2^2(-r_1x_1(0) + x_2(0))}\bigg]
    \end{aligned}
  \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentcass
`

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Command \arctan already defined.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    \vec{x}_1(t) &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      x_1^{(1)}(t)\\
      x_2^{(1)}(t)
    \end{pmatrix} =
    \mathrlap{\begin{pmatrix}
      X_1^{(1)}\cos(\omega_1t + \phi_1)\\
      r_1X_1^{(1)}\cos(\omega_1t + \phi_1)
    \end{pmatrix}}\\
    \vec{x}_2(t) &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      x_1^{(2)}(t)\\
      x_2^{(2)}(t)
    \end{pmatrix} =
    \mathrlap{\begin{pmatrix}
      X_1^{(2)}\cos(\omega_2t + \phi_2)\\
      r_2X_1^{(2)}\cos(\omega_2t + \phi_2)
    \end{pmatrix}}\\
    r_1 &=
      \frac{3k - m\omega_1^2}{2k} &
      X_1^{(1)} &= \frac{1}{r_2 - r_1}\bigg[(r_2x_1(0) - x_2(0))^2 +
      \frac{(-r_2\dot{x}_1(0) + \dot{x}_2(0))^2}{\omega_1^2}\bigg]^{1/2}
\\
    r_2 &=
      \frac{3k - m\omega_2^2}{2k} &
      X_1^{(2)} &= \frac{1}{r_2 - r_1}\bigg[(-r_1x_1(0) + x_2(0))^2 +
      \frac{(r_1\dot{x}_1(0) - \dot{x}_2(0))^2}{\omega_2^2}\bigg]^{1/2}
\\
    \phi_1 &=
      \arctan\bigg[\frac{-r_2\dot{x}_1(0) + \dot{x}_2(0)}
      {\omega_1^2(r_2x_1(0) - x_2(0))}\bigg] &
\phi_2 &= \arctan\bigg[\frac{r_1\dot{x}_1(0) - \dot{x}_2(0)}
      {\omega_2^2(-r_1x_1(0) + x_2(0))}\bigg]
  \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to leave a tad more space between the two formulas on the last line.  a `\quad` before the `\phi` should fix that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes I thought same after posting the image, but I had to leave the house to collect a boy:-)

Comment: Here's a case where it makes a considerable difference in the output if one writes `\arctan\bigg[` or `\arctan\biggl[`. The former code tells TeX to insert a thinspace (inappropriately, I believe) between `arctan` and the opening square bracket; this doesn't happen if you write `\arctan\biggl[`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144439/5001 for further examples of why it pays to use `\biggl[` and `\biggr]` instead of `\bigg[` and `\bigg]`. Shameless self-citation alert!!

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what's supposed to be achieved by the proposed layout and the attendant alignment of various `=` symbols. Rather than create the impression that various equations are related in ways that are probably not intended, I'd simplify the layout and get by with a single `align*` environment and use `\qquad` statements to insert some horizontal whitespace where needed. Observe that it's important to use `\biggl[` instead of just `\bigg[` following the two `\arctan` statements; if you omit the `l` (mathopen) specifiers, LaTeX will insert an inappropriate whitespace.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align*" and "pmatrix" environments
\usepackage{newpxtext}             % Palatino text font
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm} % Euler math font
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \vec{x}_1(t) &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      x_1^{(1)}(t)\\
      x_2^{(1)}(t)
    \end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      X_1^{(1)}\cos(\omega_1t + \phi_1)\\
      r_1X_1^{(1)}\cos(\omega_1t + \phi_1)
    \end{pmatrix}\\
    \vec{x}_2(t) &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      x_1^{(2)}(t)\\
      x_2^{(2)}(t)
    \end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      X_1^{(2)}\cos(\omega_2t + \phi_2)\\
      r_2X_1^{(2)}\cos(\omega_2t + \phi_2)
    \end{pmatrix}\\[2ex]  % additional vertical space
    r_1 &=
      \frac{3k - m\omega_1^2}{2k} \qquad
      X_1^{(1)} = \frac{1}{r_2 - r_1}\biggl[(r_2x_1(0) - x_2(0))^2 +
      \frac{(-r_2\dot{x}_1(0) + \dot{x}_2(0))^2}{\omega_1^2}\biggr]^{1/2}\\
    r_2 &=
      \frac{3k - m\omega_2^2}{2k}  \qquad
      X_1^{(2)} = \frac{1}{r_2 - r_1}\biggl[(-r_1x_1(0) + x_2(0))^2 +
      \frac{(r_1\dot{x}_1(0) - \dot{x}_2(0))^2}{\omega_2^2}\biggr]^{1/2}\\[2ex] % additional vertical space
    \phi_1 &=
      \arctan\biggl[\frac{-r_2\dot{x}_1(0) + \dot{x}_2(0)}
      {\omega_1^2(r_2x_1(0) - x_2(0))}\biggr] \qquad
      \phi_2 = \arctan\biggl[\frac{r_1\dot{x}_1(0) - \dot{x}_2(0)}
      {\omega_2^2(-r_1x_1(0) + x_2(0))}\biggr]
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just look at @davidcarisle answer to understand what was supposed to be achieved.

Comment: @dustin - I know what you said you wanted, and I understand that David's answer provides what you say you want. However, I honestly don't think that the requested alignments are particularly effective in enhancing an understanding of the material. That's why I proposed an alternative and simpler layout. You are, naturally, free to disregard my opinion.