# Height of "parentheses, brackets, braces"

Tags: amsmath

I wonder if there could be a tricky automated way to detect fractions within "parentheses, brackets, braces" to adjust their heights to the maximum height of the candidates. See picture below and highlighted in yellow.

[image]

The minimal example is given by:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
I_x&=\int y^2\,\underbrace{\text{d}A}_{=\text{d}x\text{d}y}=4\left(\int    \limits_{x=0}^{\frac{B}{2}-\frac{b}{2}}\int \limits_{y=0}^{\frac{H}{2}}y^2\,\text{d}y\text{d}x+\int\limits_{x=\frac{B}{2}-\frac{b}{2}}^{\frac{B}{2}}\int \limits_{y=\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{H}{2}}y^2\,\text{d}y\text{d}x\right)\\
&=4\left(\left[x\right]_{x=0}^{\frac{B}{2}-\frac{b}{2}}\cdot \left[\frac{1}{3}y^3\right]_{y=0}^{\frac{H}{2}}+\left[x\right]_{x= \frac{B}{2}-\frac{b}{2}}^{\frac{B}{2}}\cdot \left[\frac{1}{3}y^3\right]_{y=\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{H}{2}}\right)\\
&=\frac{BH^3-bh^3}{12}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Any hints appreciated. As told above - the target is to detect the fractions and then adjust the height to all other parentheses, brackets, braces alike.

The way I did looks quite ugly to my sense of good typing ...

Hope I was precise enough!

Comment: If you want all braces/parens to be of a fixed size, use `\big`, `\bigg`, `\Big`, or `\Bigg` instead of `\left...\right`.

Comment: Yes, I know - I was asking about how to detect the fractions and therefore automatically get the correct height for the other candidates and if no fractions inside - take the normal height as given by \left...\right ... I thought there could be a solution with LaTeX3 and xparse to make such detection  ...

Comment: Well considering how easy it is for your editor to change all at once, the `\big`s to `\Bigg`s, it seems trivial to just do it with the editor, rather than writing code to detect and remedy it.

Comment: @JürgenG In mathematical mode it is deprecable to use `\text{d}`; you should use `\mathrm{...}` or for bold simbol `\mathbf`.

Comment: Definitely you are right, that is not my major problem. Considering the solution of Sebastiano - of course this does the job. However does this look better? With detection of fractions I was thinking of finding fractions that only contain NUMBERS to then then use \tfrac{}{} compared to functions that contain \frac{x^2}{x^2-1} or so which seem to be displystyle ... I seem to not have been precise enough, sorry about that. Of course I can do that manually integral by integral, but there are hundreds of them which I like to get under "typesetting fine" control.

Comment: @JürgenG, have you considered accepting an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\let\zzfrac\frac
\def\frac#1#2{\afterassignment\zzztest\count0=0#1#2\relax{#1}{#2}}
\def\zzztest#1\relax{%
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \expandafter\tfrac
\else
  \expandafter\zzfrac
\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
I_x&=\int y^2\,\underbrace{\mathrm{d}A}_{=\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y}=4\left(\int    \limits_{x=0}^{\frac{B}{2}-\frac{b}{2}}\int \limits_{y=0}^{\frac{H}{2}}y^2\,\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x+\int\limits_{x=\frac{B}{2}-\frac{b}{2}}^{\frac{B}{2}}\int \limits_{y=\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{H}{2}}y^2\,\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=4\left(\left[x\right]_{x=0}^{\frac{B}{2}-\frac{b}{2}}\cdot \left[\frac{1}{3}y^3\right]_{y=0}^{\frac{H}{2}}+\left[x\right]_{x= \frac{B}{2}-\frac{b}{2}}^{\frac{B}{2}}\cdot \left[\frac{1}{3}y^3\right]_{y=\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{H}{2}}\right)\\
&=\frac{BH^3-bh^3}{12}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This switches between `\frac` and `\tfrac` which means if you use `\frac` in a subscript it might do the wrong thing and use `\tfrac` it could be made smarter but to be honest. I wouldn't it gets more fragile and it is more robust just to use `\tfrac{1}{3}` in the original source of you want a third.

Comment: Egregious David. 
My philosophy is always to recognize and appreciate the different forms of writing in mathematical mode, especially for users who are very good as you. I told the user that each of us has a way of writing any mathematical document in relation to our tastes. +1

Comment: David, this comes along much closer to what I want!!! Thank you very much for that approach!!!

Answer (score 5):

I prefer for brackets and parentheses this version. Each of us has a style to write mathematical formulas. The style which suits the most to you would be this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
I_x&=\int y^2\underbrace{\mathrm{d}A}_{=\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y}=4\left(\int \limits_{x=0}^{\frac{B}{2}-\frac{b}{2}}\int \limits_{y=0}^{\frac{H}{2}}y^2\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x+\int\limits_{x=\frac{B}{2}-\frac{b}{2}}^{\frac{B}{2}}\int \limits_{y=\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{H}{2}}y^2\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=4\left(\bigg[x\bigg]_{x=0}^{\frac{B}{2}-\frac{b}{2}}\cdot \left[\frac{1}{3}y^3\right]_{y=0}^{\frac{H}{2}}+\bigg[x\bigg]_{x= \frac{B}{2}-\frac{b}{2}}^{\frac{B}{2}}\cdot \left[\frac{1}{3}y^3\right]_{y=\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{H}{2}}\right)\\
&=\frac{BH^3-bh^3}{12}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\biggl` for left and `\biggr` for right, to make sure spacing gets properly adjusted.

Comment: Kind Steven yes of course. Before I have seen, quickly, this link: https://it.sharelatex.com/learn/Brackets_and_Parentheses. Now I have seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19480/why-use-the-control-sequences-bigl-biggl-bigr-or-biggr-as-i-can-always-us. Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Comment: @JürgenG We are here to help us all. At least that's the spirit that hovers in me for this site. If you like my answer you can check V green.

Comment: @JürgenG If you like my answer or of another user you can see this link: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer.