# Equations with summation ("\sum") symbols

Tags: equations

Can some one please help me how can I make the following equation in latex?

[image]

I have used

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq24}
\begin{split}
V^{\pi}(s) = {\sum_{a}\pi(s,a)}
\sum_{s^'} \mathcal{P}{{^a}_{{ss}^'}}  \bigg[{\mathcal{R}{{^a}_{{ss}^'}}} 
      + \gamma {V^{\pi}}(s^') \bigg] 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

But latex does not compile as it says error

Comment: Simply type `s'` (and the like) instead of `s^'`

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped

Comment: `\bigg[` and `\bigg]` should be `\biggl[` and `\biggr]` respectively. Also `\mathcal{P}{{^a}_{{ss}^'}}` should be more simply `\mathcal{P}^{a}_{ss'}`

Comment: Why do you use `split`? Do you think that `split` means you can have the content/input *split* across multiple lines?

Answer (score 6):

Generally `'` doesnot require `^`, hence this character already in `superscript` position in all font by default, if you need `^` then you have to use `\prime` instead of `'`, refer the below tags:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq24}
V^{\pi}(s) = \sum_{a}\pi(s,a)
\sum_{s^{\prime}} \mathcal{P}{{^a}_{{ss}^{\prime}}}
\biggl[{\mathcal{R}{{^a}_{{ss}^{\prime}}}} + \gamma
{V^{\pi}}(s^{\prime}) \biggr] 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

PS: No need to use `split` environment in this case...

Comment: this is a bit misleading as `s'` in TeX does not use a superscript because `'` is in superscript position in the font but because the latex (and plain tex) macros convert `'` in math mode to `^{\prime}` . So you never need to use `^{\prime}` it is just a long way of writing `'`.  Also you have several errors copied from the code in the question `\bigg` should be `\biggl` etc, see the comment egreg made under the question.

Answer (score 6):

Writing `f'` is the same as writing `f^{\prime}`; for double primes, it is `f''` and so on. The code `^'` is wrong.

Besides, there are also wrong (not just useless) braces in your code:

```latex
\begin{equation} \label{eq:Vpi(s)}
V^{\pi}(s) = \sum_{a}\pi(s,a) \sum_{s'} 
  \mathcal{P}^{a}_{ss'}  \bigl[\mathcal{R}^{a}_{ss'} + \gamma V^{\pi}(s') \bigr] 
\end{equation}
```

Use `\biggl[` and `\biggr]` instead of the unqualified `\bigg` in order to give the brackets their correct nature of delimiters. However, the size is too big: `\bigl[` and `\bigr]` are sufficient.

It's also better to use *semantic* names for the labels, rather than `eq24` as the number might change during preparation of the document. If you use `\label{eq:Vpi(s)}` (or whatever you prefer), the references will not depend on the actual number.

See the code below if you really want staggered subscripts and superscripts.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

Your formula (with the main fixes)
\begin{equation} \label{eq24}
\begin{split}
V^{\pi}(s) = {\sum_{a}\pi(s,a)}
\sum_{s'} \mathcal{P}{{^a}_{{ss}'}}  \bigg[{\mathcal{R}{{^a}_{{ss}'}}} + \gamma {V^{\pi}}(s') \bigg] 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The same with the suggested fixes
\begin{equation} \label{eq:Vpi(s)}
V^{\pi}(s) = \sum_{a}\pi(s,a) \sum_{s'} 
  \mathcal{P}^{a}_{ss'}  \bigl[\mathcal{R}^{a}_{ss'} + \gamma V^{\pi}(s') \bigr] 
\end{equation}

If you want staggered superscripts and subscripts, it's better to use tensor
\begin{equation} \label{eq:Vpi(s)mod}
V^{\pi}(s) = \sum_{a}\pi(s,a) \sum_{s'} 
  \tensor{\mathcal{P}}{^{a}_{ss'}}
  \bigl[\tensor{\mathcal{R}}{^{a}_{ss'}} + \gamma V^{\pi}(s') \bigr] 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't it enough to just use \left[...\right] instead of \bigl[...\bigr]?

Comment: @Diaa Try it and see.

Answer (score 2):

The rule is we write `X_{subscript}^{superscript}`, but braces around a single character, or a single command that functions for this purpose as a single character, are unnecessary. As this includes the case where `X` is the summation operator, we don't need any more braces (except around the arguments of [non-nullary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity#Nullary) commands such as `\mathcal`). One can thus use

```
V^\pi\left(s\right)=\sum_a\pi\left(s,\,a\right)\sum_{s^\prime}\mathcal{P}_{ss^\prime}^a\left[\mathcal{R}_{ss^\prime}^a+\gamma V^\pi\left(s^\prime\right)\right]
```

where I have used `\left` and `\right` in front of parentheses to resize them according to their contents, and `\,` for a space between the `\pi` function's arguments. You can preview the result [here](https://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php?latex=V%5E%5Cpi%5Cleft(s%5Cright)=%5Csum_a%5Cpi%5Cleft(s,%5C,a%5Cright)%5Csum_%7Bs%5E%5Cprime%7D%5Cmathcal%7BP%7D_%7Bss%5E%5Cprime%7D%5Ea%5Cleft[%5Cmathcal%7BR%7D_%7Bss%5E%5Cprime%7D%5Ea+%5Cgamma&space;V%5E%5Cpi%5Cleft(s%5E%5Cprime%5Cright)%5Cright]).

I say one *can* do that, but the square brackets look a little smaller that way than in your original image. I'm torn between whether `\left[` and `\right]` should be respectively replaced with `\big[` and `\big]`, or `\bigg[` and `\bigg]`, [or even these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19480/why-use-the-control-sequences-bigl-biggl-bigr-or-biggr-as-i-can-always-us). (Using `\Big` or `\Bigg` leads to still larger brackets, far beyond what you wanted, but this is worth knowing for other use cases.) You're welcome to also experiment with removing the `\left` and `\right` in front of some pairs of round brackets altogether, but in the case of `s^\prime` you'd probably regret it.