# How can I increase the size of the Floor signs in an Equation

Tags: symbols, size

I have the following equation:

```tex
    \begin{equation*}
        t \leq \lfloor {(\frac{R}{\rho})}^2 \rfloor
    \end{equation*}
```

the output looks like this:

[image: Output]

While I want it to look like this:

[image: tareget]

where the floor signs look more nice.

can you please tell me what to do? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before someone suggests `\left` and `\right`... `:-)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
t \leq \biggl\lfloor \biggl(\frac{R}{\rho}\biggr)^{\!\!2} \biggr\rfloor
\end{equation*} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the small negative space added in the exponent.

My personal preference goes to `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`, which allows you to choose the scaling if you *really* want to:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\floor[\bigg]{\biggl(\frac{R}{\rho}\biggr)^{\!\!2}}
\qquad \floor*{\biggl(\frac{R}{\rho}\biggr)^{\!\!2}} % automatic scaling with left/right
\end{equation*} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

I find the second version horrible but that is just my personal taste...

Answer (score 3):

These are two standard ways to go:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    t \leq \lfloor {(\frac{R}{\rho})}^2 \rfloor
\end{equation*} 

\begin{equation*}
    t \leq \left\lfloor {\left(\frac{R}{\rho}\right)}^2 \right\rfloor
\end{equation*} 

\begin{equation*}
    t \leq \biggl\lfloor {\biggl(\frac{R}{\rho}\biggr)}^2 \biggr\rfloor
\end{equation*} 

\end{document}
```

There is also an alternative with https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools.

[image]

**Related:**

- [How to make \left, \right pairs of delimiter work over multiple lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/how-to-make-left-right-pairs-of-delimiter-work-over-multiple-lines/21291#21291)
- [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right/173771#173771)
- [Why use the control sequences \bigl, \biggl, \bigr or \biggr, as I can always use \big or \bigg?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19480/why-use-the-control-sequences-bigl-biggl-bigr-or-biggr-as-i-can-always-us)
- [Big Parenthesis in an Equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38868/big-parenthesis-in-an-equation)
- [Spacing around \left and \right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right)
- [automatic size adjustment for nested parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36039/automatic-size-adjustment-for-nested-parentheses)