# How to use \left and \right inside text environment

Tags: symbols, delimiters, text-manipulation, text-mode

I would like to know how to use the `\left` and `\right` options in the text environment.

This is what I am trying to do:

`\left( when factorizing $e^{-2000t}$\right)`

As you can see, I am trying to make the parenthesis to be as big as what is inside (That was just an example, it could be something bigger).

Thanks in advantage for helping.

Comment: Is the actual construction inside an equation, or part of the regular flow of paragraph text? If it's the latter, do you want the text to be breakable across lines?

Comment: Is part of the regular flow of a paragraph text, and I would like it to be breakable across lines. (Thanks for answering).

Comment: There is no reason for making parentheses taller in this case. Normal size suffices. Nothing imposes that parentheses must cover the whole height of a math formula and a small overshoot frequently makes for a better effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended solving it by `$\left( \vphantom{e^{-2000t}}\right.$when facotirzing~$e^{-2000t}$ $\left. \vphantom{e^{-2000t}}\right)$`. As my document (*IEEEtran journal*) won't allow the \bigl and \bigr commands.

I don't have yet an automated `\newcommand` because I don't know how to do it and it is kind of tricky as I would have to type in the taller input inside the `\vphantom` parameter everytime. But this is the best solution (I've found so far) as the height is automatically adjusted everytime, not having to change the delimiter size.

Answer (score 6):

I would just create new commands for these "text-style" delimiters using `\bigl` and `\bigr`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\textbigl}[1]{$\bigl#1$\nobreak}
\newcommand{\textbigr}[1]{\nobreak$\bigr#1$}
\begin{document}
Here is some regular text and then it is obvious that it might
\textbigl(when factorizing~$e^{-2000t}$\textbigr) when 
you consider this.
\end{document}
```

The `\big`-style delimiter-sizing provides better spacing around content than `\left`-`\right` pairs, and also is convenient when wanting to keep the resized height across break points.

Ps. I won't do this myself.

Comment: Thanks for answering (again). Would this work when have really bigger information inside the parenthesis?.

Comment: @Hans: For that one can define alternative `\textbig`-like commands. See the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) (section **4.14.1 Delimiter sizes**, p 15) (and [Difference between `\big[` and `\bigl[`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1232/5764)). I would not place content that is too tall/deep inside regular text, since it forces improper `\baselineskip`.