# \Bigl( \Bigr) not working

Tags: equations

I'm trying this to use `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)`, but even a simple equation as this one is not working

```
\begin{align*}
     \Bigl( a b \Bigr)
\end{align*}
```

any solutions would be grateful

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a minimal, but compilable code example (MWE).

Comment: And say what you mean by "not working".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is lazy. ;-)

Comment: I mean that I'm getting this error ! Missing { inserted.

Comment: @Diana  Please put you full example which produces this error. The presented fragment is correct, so the source of your problem must somewhere outside it.

Answer (score 1):

Environment align* is defined by package amsmath:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \Bigl( a b \Bigr)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This code works fine.

Comment: But it's not working; I'm already using \usepackage{amsmath}

Comment: Sorry, but it works fine. I have tried.

Comment: \bigl should be \big only

Comment: @Diana No. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/difference-between-big-and-bigl